# What to use instead of AudioPlaybackState, cannot find the documentation

Tags: flutter, just-audio

I was looking at a clients app but I cannot find the solution. It was a really old code and I have updated the just_audio plugin to the latest version and i am getting errors in the code below I don't know what to do. I understand the mapping but I don't know what to write instead of "AudioPlaybackState".

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:online_radio/radio/radio_player.dart';
import 'package:online_radio/radio/radio_state.dart';

class JustAudioPlayer extends RadioPlayer {
  final AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  Stream<RadioState> radioStateStream;

  JustAudioPlayer() {
    radioStateStream = _audioPlayer.playbackStateStream.map(_mapToRadioState);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setUrl(String url) async {
    return _audioPlayer.setUrl(url);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> play({@required String url}) async {
    return _audioPlayer.play();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> pause() {
    return _audioPlayer.pause();
  }

  RadioState _mapToRadioState(AudioPlaybackState audioState) {
    switch (audioState) {
      case AudioPlaybackState.none:
      case AudioPlaybackState.stopped:
        return RadioState.STOPPED;
      case AudioPlaybackState.paused:
        return RadioState.PAUSED;
      case AudioPlaybackState.playing:
        return RadioState.PLAYING;
      default:
        return RadioState.UNKNOWN;
    }
  }
}
```

These are the errors i am getting:

[image: These are the errors i am getting]

[image: Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably something you could have found by reading their current documentation. Specifically this section (https://github.com/ryanheise/just_audio/tree/minor/just_audio#working-with-state-streams):

```
player.playerStateStream.listen((state) {
  if (state.playing) ... else ...
  switch (state.processingState) {
    case ProcessingState.idle: ...
    case ProcessingState.loading: ...
    case ProcessingState.buffering: ...
    case ProcessingState.ready: ...
    case ProcessingState.completed: ...
  }
});

// See also:
// - durationStream
// - positionStream
// - bufferedPositionStream
// - sequenceStateStream
// - sequenceStream
// - currentIndexStream
// - icyMetadataStream
// - playingStream
// - processingStateStream
// - loopModeStream
// - shuffleModeEnabledStream
// - volumeStream
// - speedStream
// - playbackEventStream
```

As you can see there are now multiple streams which can be used to achieve the same behaviour as before:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:just_audio/just_audio.dart';
import 'package:online_radio/radio/radio_player.dart';
import 'package:online_radio/radio/radio_state.dart';

class JustAudioPlayer extends RadioPlayer {
  final AudioPlayer _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
  Stream<RadioState> radioStateStream;

  JustAudioPlayer() {
    radioStateStream = _audioPlayer.playerStateStream.map(_mapToRadioState);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> setUrl(String url) async {
    return _audioPlayer.setUrl(url);
  }

  @override
  Future<void> play({@required String url}) async {
    return _audioPlayer.play();
  }

  @override
  Future<void> pause() {
    return _audioPlayer.pause();
  }

  RadioState _mapToRadioState(PlayerState playerState) {
    final processingState = playerState?.processingState;
    final playing = playerState?.playing;


    if (playing == true) return RadioState.PLAYING;
    if (processingState == ProcessingState.completed || 
         processingState == ProcessingState.idle) return RadioState.STOPPED;
    if (processingState == ProcessingState.ready) return RadioState.PAUSED;
    return RadioState.UNKNOWN;
    }
  }
}
```

Please note: This code was not tested and you should do more testing to make sure that it works in the way you need it.